# Vertically align <li> text & <img> with Tweet jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working with the seaofclouds 'Tweet' plugin on a website that I'm building:

http://tinyurl.com/c88fx5j

The Tweet plugin is prebuilt utilizing jQuery & CSS and I've figured out how to style the plugin to my liking via CSS, but the li items not being vertically aligned with the Twitter user's Avatar is throwing me off and I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'd like to vertically align the li text in the mdidle with the Twitter avatar to the left of each post, how can this be done?

**My CSS:**

```
   .tweet,
.query {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}

    .tweet_list {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background-color: #fff;

    }


        .tweet_list li {
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding: 0.5em;
            list-style-type: none;
            vertical-align: middle;         
            display: inline-block;


        }


        .tweet_list li a {
                color: #0099FF;
                text-decoration:underline;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

        .tweet_list .tweet_even {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .tweet_list .tweet_avatar {
            padding-right: 15px;
            float: left;


        }

            .tweet_list .tweet_avatar img {

                width:60px;
                height:60px;

            }
```

**HTML is brief, just a wrap to contain the Tweets:**

```
/*Tweet*/

    #tweet-wrap {   
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 160px;
        width: 960px;
        height: 160px;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The text looks fine (vertically aligned) in the link you've provided.

Comment: Yes, just saw that, there's some css, `line-height: 4`, please remove that, that will, however mess up your vertical alignment

Comment: Is the `html` structure made by you? or is it auto-generated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21296/discussion-between-badzoke-and-willard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the following styles in the appropriate `css` files,

```
.tweet_list li {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
}

.tweet_list .tweet_avatar {
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.tweet_time {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 57px;
    min-width: 108px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.tweet_join {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 56px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.tweet_text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**PS**: the css fix for the `...` functionality (we discussed in chat), doesn't work for sentences/nested html elements, so you'd probably have to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After inspect your code, I think that you just need to specify `line-height` for each of your `li` inside your `tweet_list` and it should be fine:

```
ul.tweet_list li {
    line-height: 4em;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

**UPDATED**

OK, the first solution seem lousy in case more than 1 line of text, I'm a bit lazy here so if I were you, I'll make use of this solution, try this and tell me if anything gone wrong with this approach:

```
.tweet_list li .tweet_time, .tweet_join, .tweet_text {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input - that helped to center the first line of text, but the second line overflows & is too far from the top. See my web link for results.

Comment: Updated to original CSS - Close but not quite, thank you for the input.